# Automatically increase number everyday / Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I coded a SwiftUI App, and the User can choose how much days are left. For example he choose 20 days, it should count in a Circle. For example 10 days are done, the circle should be at 50%.
So I thought I create a Int that is everyday increasing by one. When the user choose 20 days, the Int should start to increase and after 10 days for example the Int is at 10 and because the user choose 20 days, the circle should be at 50%.
Days / Int(that is increasing)
But I dont know how to code the Int that is increasing everyday.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Instead of storing an incrementing integer, store the date/time when the countdown started, and calculate the result of day difference between the stored date and the current time when your view is rendered

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the suggestion of storing the start date and using today's date to know how many days have passed, you can use this extension

```
extension Date {
    func daysSinceDate(_ fromDate: Date = Date()) -> Int {
        let earliest = self < fromDate ? self  : fromDate
        let latest = (earliest == self) ? fromDate : self

        let earlierComponents:DateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: earliest)
        let laterComponents:DateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: latest)
        guard
            let earlierDay = earlierComponents.day,
            let laterDay = laterComponents.day,
            laterDay >= earlierDay
            else {
            return 0
        }
        return laterDay - earlierDay
    }

    func dateForDaysFromNow(_ days: Int) -> Date? {
        var dayComponent = DateComponents()
        dayComponent.day = days
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dayComponent, to: self)
    }
}
```